# Render events for one year displaying a date range of 40 days in ResourceTimeline

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am in the process to add FullCalendar v4 to our react application and I'm pretty new to FullCalendar, so excuse me if I ask a basic question.

I searched both the documentation and StackOverflow, but couldn't find any hints to my current problem. Let me briefly describe our goal scenario:

We want to load and render the events for a whole year and show a date range of about 40 days (a whole month and additionally 5 days from the last and the next month) to the user. The user should be able to scroll through the whole year with the scrollbar.

The first question is whether FC4 already provides the functionality with which we can achieve our goal. I tried to define a custom view of type 'resourceTimeline' with a duration of 30 days and additionally set the 'validRange' to the current year. This gives me the look I want, but unfortunately it is static - the scrollbar is not visible as long as the screen can display the whole area of 40 days. With the next/previous buttons I can switch between the 40 days segments, but I'd rather use these buttons to switch between years and use the scrollbar to scroll within the year.

We have now tried to set the 'visibleRange' to the current year and programmatically scroll to the current date in the 'datesRender' function. The problem is that we can't decide whether FC4 was initially loaded (where we would scroll to the current date) or whether a user scrolled manually to another date in the timeline and edited an event there. In this case the scroll position should be kept.

So what we are missing is the matching callback that tells us that the 'executeRender' function has been completely executed. The question at this point is how and where I can provide an application specific callback function that is triggered after all dates and events have been rendered. I also saw several internal success callbacks. Is it possible to overwrite them?

Any ideas and hints are highly appreciated.
Thank you very much for thinking along.

Comment: you can't do what you're asking, no. You've got no control over the width of the days as rendered, so even if you fixed the width of the calendar you'd never be sure it would display exactly 40 days. And yeah scrolling to a specific day in the timeline is problematic. You're better off with your first solution - a range of 40 days, and then use next/previous buttons to move between the segments. That's how fullCalendar is designed to be used. Also, if you have a lot of events, you might find performance isn't great when you try to load a whole year's worth at once.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The amount of events and the corresponding performance is not critical in our case, because our application framework caches the data and the amount of events is manageable. So far we have not noticed any blatant performance issues.

Using the 'eventSourceSuccess' function I found a way to react to the first initialization of FC4.